# Como apagar os símbolos de um CPF em um input?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um site que pede o nome e o CPF da pessoa o CPF tem que estar no formato `xxx.xxx.xxx-xx`. E ao apertar o botão ele cadastra a pessoa(Os dados só são exibidos na tela). Mas eu resolvi criar um script que completa automaticamente os símbolos do CPF quando o usuário começa a digitar que é o `.` e o `-`. Mas o script sim, funciona ele autocompleta os símbolos só que ao tentar apagar não apaga, olhem o código esse é um protótipo do script do projeto que estou criando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input id="box" type="text" maxlength="14">

    <script>

      var box = window.document.querySelector("#box");

      box.addEventListener("input", function()
      {
          switch (box.value.length)
          {
              case 3:
                  box.value += ".";
                  break;
              case 7:
                  box.value += ".";
                  break;
              case 11:
                  box.value += "-";
          }
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notem, que ao digitar o CPF eu não consigo apagar os símbolos porque estou usando o `event input` no `input`. Assim cada vez que eu modificar os dados dentro do `input` o `event input` sera chamado e caira lá no `switch` e  irar executar o `case 11:`, isso porque o `box.value.length` sera igual a `11`. Assim cada vez que você tentar apagar, não dá porque ele sempre vai cair no `case 11:`, então este é meu problema não consigo apagar os símbolos. Como eu fasso para apagalos?, sem deixar de usar o `event input` ?, pois eu necessito deste `event` no script para poder atualizar automaticamente os simbolos ao vivo para o usuário, assim ele não vai ter o trabalho de digitalos e irar melhorar mais a experiência dele com o meu site.

Comment: ao meu ver você ta tentando reinventar a roda, ja existe lib pra isso https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Eu acho que ele não quer um lib,e sim script simples e puro

Comment: Eu olhei é bem interesante essa lib, mas o problema é que eu queria com js puro.

Comment: é uma ótima ideia @LucasMiranda, mas e se ele não quiser usar jquery? no código dele está usando javascript puro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro uma solução mais elaborada, mas mais robusta e flexível, que não lhe causa problemas quando apaga um numero ficando apenas com o traço no fim, ou quando acabou de apagar o traço e quer adicionar outro numero.

Na solução que apresento, eu extraio os números da caixa com uma expressão regular simples, com `/\d/g` e aplico os carateres de inserção nos pontos certos, utilizando um dicionario pré-construído para tal.

Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="box" type="text" maxlength="14">

    <script>
      const box = document.querySelector("#box");
      const insercoes = {
        3: ".",
        7: ".",
        11: "-"
      };

      box.addEventListener("input", function(e){
          //obter os números ou array vazio se não houver nenhum número digitado
          let nums = box.value.match(/\d/g) || []; 
          
          for (let posicaoInserir of Object.keys(insercoes)){ //para cada ponto de inserção
            //se o tamanho dos numeros é suficiente para esta posição de inserção
            if (nums.length > parseInt(posicaoInserir)){
              //inserir o caratere na posição certa
              nums.splice(parseInt(posicaoInserir), 0, insercoes[posicaoInserir]);
            }
          }
          
          box.value = nums.join(""); //colocar o novo array na caixa
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

O remover funciona corretamente sem ser preciso fazer mais nada devido ao teste `nums.length > parseInt(posicaoInserir)`. Se tiver a quantidade de carateres até ao traço ele não aplica nenhum traço e por isso permite remover. Só quando tem mais carateres é que aplica o caratere de inserção no meio.

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: Valeu, amigo funcionou perfeito!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode adicionar outros cases cortando a string na posição onde tem os caracteres, eu utilizei no exemplo o método [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```js
var box = window.document.querySelector("#box");

box.addEventListener("input", function() {
  switch (box.value.length) {
    case 3:
      box.value += ".";
      break;
    case 7:
      box.value += ".";
      break;
    case 11:
      box.value += "-";
      break;
    case 12:
      box.value = box.value.substr(0, box.value.length-1);
      break;
    case 8:
      box.value = box.value.substr(0, box.value.length-1);
      break;
    case 4:
      box.value = box.value.substr(0, box.value.length-1);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="box" type="text" maxlength="14">
```

> **OBS: Quando são apagados os caracteres `.` ou `-`, faz-se necessário apagar mais um número para poder voltar a preencher os campo com valores.**

Comment: Opa, valeu ajudou muito, obrigado!

Comment: A sua solução não funciona bem quando acaba de apagar um traço e quer voltar a escrever números, ou quando acabou de inserir um traço e quer apagar logo de seguida.

Comment: @Isac Sim sim, seu exemplo é bem mais completo e é o que deveria ficar como resposta realmente, apenas implementei uma forma aplicando a lógica dele utilizando **case**. Vou colocar uma observação na resposta, que após apagar o caractere faz-se necessário apagar mais um para poder voltar a preencher o campo novamente.